# How to disable tqdm progress bars from outside the module it is used

Tags: python, python-module, tqdm

I am working with neural prophet module for timeseries forecasting. While using it I got tones of progress bars which I don't want due to some reasons. Some of them I was able to disable but the progress bar generated from tqdm is still coming. This tqdm is used inside neuralprophet module so can't change it. Ex. disable=True, leave=False will not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite the `tqdm` class in the top of your code with something that does nothing...

```py
import tqdm

def tqdm_replacement(iterable_object,*args,**kwargs):
    return iterable_object
tqdm_copy = tqdm.tqdm # store it if you want to use it later
tqdm.tqdm = tqdm_replacement

# import any other module you need after this line
```

then as an example (this next code can be anywhere after the above code)

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(5)):
    print(i)
```

the output contains no progress bar, and if you want to use a progress bar in your code then you can use the `tqdm_copy` object yourself.
you should also do the same for other iterators inside tqdm if the progress bar is still there.

note that it is best if you run the code to disable tqdm before you import any of the modules that use it to guarantee this will work.